# What happens to all your trading cards when you vote?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

My steam level is 2. I don't really intend on buying things to level up.

However, I do vote for the next flash sale item every time there is a sale. As a result, I have collected many trading cards that I supposedly get when I am level 5. Will said cards ever disappear? Is there a deadline for me to collect them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the other steam trading cards the "snow globes" you get by voting have an expiration date which is **Jan 03 2014** ,when the sale ends.

[image]

Here it says it is valid untill Jan 04,but it is just the matter of time zone.

Comment: Do all of them expire at some point?

Comment: If by them you mean snow globes,then yes.

Comment: No, I mean any trading cards earned by voting. Like the ones in the summer sale.

Comment: oh,no they don't expire.This year's summer cards are still here.Until now the snow globes are the only cards with expiration date I have seen.